# How to have a higher level function check variables within lower functions via pass by reference?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-reference-value

We haven't really covered pointers but have been learning about passing by reference (the `&` pointer will be covered later). In an exercise, we were asked to write a small question game that would pass values in a simple one class `main` program between its functions to get things done.

If we have a hierarchy where `main` calls 2 functions: function `askNum`, and function `giveStats`, with `askNum` having a host of functions inside (one on the lower level being `checkIfRight`). I need to call `giveStats` which would basically tell the user how well they've guessed over a set of questions.

I am glossing over the details because I want to focus on the fact that we can't use value returning functions or global variables. So I have to figure out a way to count the number of guesses correct within `checkIfRight` and send that info back up the hierarchy of functions to `giveStats`.

I am not sure how to call it though. I have most of the code figured out for this game and implemented simple *pass by reference* on functions in the same hierarchy, I am confused about having a function outside basically call it. So would there be a variable in main called `numCorrect` and `giveStats` would call it after `askNum` modifies it?

Comment: I guess if you present some code with the functions and what you are doing, then it will be easier to take it further.

Comment: Please post your question so that it can pass the criteria of [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Narrow your question with a specific code sample. Vague descriptions are too broad, and are not a good fit for the SO format.